# Selecting specific elements when using the body as the delegate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand that its recommended to use the body as the delegate for .on() events:

```
$('body').on('click', 'button', function() {
    $('input[type="checked"]').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Where I run into trouble is when trying to select specific elements but of the same type. So for instance if I have a button with a unique class, id, etc I end up selecting the first button within the DOM.

```
$('body').on('click', $('button#clear'), function() {
    $('input[type="checked"]').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Is there any workaround for this when using .on()?

**Bonus:** Is there a time where you shouldn't use the body as the delegate? If so what would be the second best alternative?

Comment: You only have to use event delegation if the element doesn't exist yet when you bind the handler, or if you want to bind the same handler to many elements. If neither is case, bind the handler directly.

Comment: `$(document)` is another one. Especially in case of dynamically added elements and if you don't know where exactly...

Comment: @NikTerentyev Thanks! How were you able to format code in the comments btw? Never knew this was possible until now.

Comment: @CarlEdwards dunno, there is a link on a right side of the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body` isn't the recommended per se, it's just a safe bet that it will work since your target element is probably a child of `body` - in reality, you should use the static container for your AJAX content as your initial selector, eg:

```
<div id="container">
    <!--I GET POPULATED WITH AJAX CONTENT-->
    <input id="ajaxInput" /> <!--I came from an AJAX call-->
</div>
```

Now you could use

```
$("body").on("click", "#ajaxInput", function() { });
```

But this will run the check each time the `body` is clicked. A much better selector would be:

```
$("#container").on("click", "#ajaxInput", function() { });
```

Comment: Is there any way to select jQuery objects like: $('button:first') or is it just limited to ids and classes?

Comment: @CarlEdwards: You can use any selector that jQuery supports: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/, or even create your own pseudo-selectors.